# Is the AppNameAppDelegate.h and .m the entry points for all apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking at the source for: https://github.com/intabulas/ipivotal/blob/master/Classes/iPivotalAppDelegate.m

It looks like the "main" file for an iphone app, since it has a reference to the UIApplication, am I correct?

How is it that there is a .h file and in the .m file there is another block of code for the @interface with the same name?

I guess its allowed to redefine or continue the declaration of an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically correct, `-[<UIApplicationDelegate> applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` is the entry point for an application's custom code (the real entry point is actually `UIApplicationMain()`, but I wouldn't try re-implementing that if I were you).

The "second `@interface`" in the .m file is a *category*, which allows you define extra methods that aren't defined in the class's main interface. This can be used either to break a class over multiple files, to add functionality to an existing class or (as here) to keep some method definitions private.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, the AppNameAppDelegate class is where you put all the application-level code.

What happens below the covers is that the `main()` function calls the Cocoa framework's initialization function, which loads a NIB that contains the app delegate.  The `UIApplication` object (supplied by the framework) will invoke methods of the app delegate at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue defining the @interface in the .m file in a private category, this is commonly done to have private methods and properties you do not wish to expose.